# SpriteKit Enemy colliding with each other

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have some enemies on stage in SKS and I'm setting it in code as bellow

```
enemy = self.childNodeWithName("enemy")!
enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderTypes.enemy.rawValue
enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderTypes.player.rawValue
enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderTypes.player.rawValue | ColliderTypes.ground.rawValue
```

Where:

```
enum ColliderTypes: UInt32{
    case none = 0
    case all = 0xFFFFFFFF
    case ground = 0b001
    case player = 0b010
    case enemy  = 0b100
}
```

I explicitly declare I want my enemy to contact only with the ground and with the player, however they are colliding with each other. The one walking slower "drag" the one walking faster.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you handling multiple enemies in your scene? You posted code for only one enemy.

Comment: @0x141E I am running all the enemies with the same code as they have all the same configuration, I just change the name of the variable.

Comment: Do the enemies have different names in the .sks file? I suggest you check the categoryBitMask and collisionBitMask for each of the enemies to ensure they are the correct values. If they are set identically to the code you posted, they should not collide.